# Print Variable/Dynamic List of String

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of string with variable length.  I do know that the minimum length of the list is 4.  How do I print the list in the following format if the list grows to more than 4?

```
>>> strlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'] # Unknown length
>>> print ('%s %s %s %s' % (strlist [2], strlist [0], strlist [4], strlist [5]))

c a f g
```

If the list expands to

```
[..., 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

then I want the output to be

```
c a f g h i j
```

Obviously, I can't put 500 "%s" in my print function if the list expands so I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: You are printing the list elements in random order, is it intentional?

Comment: `print('%s %s %s' % (strlist[2], strlist[0], ' '.join(strlist[4:])))`?

Comment: In Python `%` is an operator for constructing strings -- not really anything to do with `print` per se. If for a given application `%` isn't adequate for getting the string that you want -- construct the string some other way and then print it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would first transform the list as required and then use `str.join()`:

```
>>> print (" ".join([strlist[2]] + [strlist[0]] + strlist[4:]))
c a f g h i j
```

Depending on your exact requirements (which are not entirely clear from your question) the transformation code might need to be different. However, the overall "transform then join" pattern still applies.

Comment: Upvote assuming we understood this weird pattern correctly

Answer (score -1):

If formatting isn't an issue, then this should work:

```
print (" ".join(strlist))
```